# With Jackson JSON library, is it possible to convert custom Objects into a string and receive a string?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to have a Custom Object, say MyDate that will only have a toString method and some constructor but I want that object to accept 'String' data and also write string data.

For example, I would have Java code:

```
public class MyDate {
 ...
}

public class RootJson {
   private MyDate myDate;
   private String id;
}

And the the json would be:
{
"myDate": "2015000000",  
"id": "2014000aabc"
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Purpose of Jackson library is to do Java <-> JSON conversions. Can you further explain what you are trying to accomplish? If you just need to accept String and write String why involve jackson? Please elaborate.

Comment: I updated the example, if you see the myDate field, I don't want to use a string by the class definition MyDate.

Comment: I updated my  answer, does this cover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, are you suggesting you want to serialize and deserialize MyDate from a String in Jackson?   This can be done with JsonDeserilizer and JsonSerilizer.  Here is an example:

```
public class JsonMyDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyDate> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String stringValue = jsonParser.getText();
        // Convert it to a MyDate how ever you want....  just example below
        return new MyDate(stringValue)
    }
}
```

And to do it in return (sterilize MyDate to JSON):

```
public class JsonMyDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyDate> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyDate myDate, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // Just an example....   convert your myDate something the jsonGenerator can handle
        jsonGenerator.writeString(myDate.toString());

    }
}
```

then you need to annotate your root class like this:

```
public class RootJson {
    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonMyDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonMyDateDeserializer.class)
   private MyDate myDate;
   private String id;
}
```

Does this cover it?

Comment: That is simple JSON conversion.  I meant at the root level class definition, how can I use a custom object.  See the updated example

Comment: Your updated code looks correct, thanks.  Don't know why the question got downvoted.